# Как вывести добавленный комментарий из БД с помощью AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax

На сайте реализовал ajax добавление и удаление комментариев в БД, а также удаление комментария со страницы. Тут было все просто. Проблема в выводе только что написанного комментария без перезагрузки. Есть код блока с комментариями:

```
<? foreach ($comments as $comment) : ?>
            <div class="comments">
                <div class="row comtext">

                    <div class="comname">
                        <?=$comment['name'];?>
                        <br>
                        <?=formatTime($comment['date']);?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="comtent">
                        <?=$comment['text'];?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="delete">
                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-light"  id="<?=$comment['id']?>">Удалить</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <? endforeach;?>
```

И запрос к БД

```
$sqlComm = 'SELECT comments.id, comments.author_id, comments.date, comments.text,
        comments.post_id, users.name FROM comments
        JOIN posts ON posts.id = comments.post_id
        JOIN users ON users.id = comments.author_id
        WHERE posts.id = ' .  $_GET['id'] .
        ' ORDER BY comments.date DESC';
```

$comments = $db->query($sqlComm);

Также вот код добавления комментария. Подозреваю, что блок с выводом этого комментария можно засунуть в .done() :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('button#add').on('click', function () {
        var text = $('textarea.text').val();
        var post_id = $('input.post_id').val();
        var user = $('input.user').val();
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "../newcom.php",
            data: {user: user,text: text, post_id: post_id}
        })
            .done(function () {
                $('textarea.text').val('');
            })
    })
});
```

Так вот, подскажите, как правильно вытягивать запись из БД и выводить ее в блоке комментариев? Спасибо.

Comment: У вас есть по крайней мере 2 варианта, чтобы сервер возвращал готовую html разметку или сервер будет возвращать JSON, а на стороне клиента скрипт будет собирать html

Comment: @ArchDemon А небольшой пример можно? Я просто в программировании в целом 3 месяца и для меня постигание этого может растянуться надолго.